# Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am using Spring 3.1, Hibernate 4 and MySQL 5.1 application and the app runs fine on my local machine. After deploying the application to web host, I am getting the following error:

```
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
```

My Spring applicationContext.xml file contains:

```
<bean id="DataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
  <property name="driverClass" value="org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver" />
  <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/brutteng_adaptiveonlinetesting" />
  <property name="user" value="XXXXXXXXXX" />
  <property name="password" value="YYYYYYYYY" />
  <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
  <property name="maxStatements" value="0" />
  <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
  <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="10800"/>
  <property name="maxIdleTime" value="21600"/>
 </bean>
```

My hibernate.cfg.xml file contains:

```
<session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/brutteng_adaptiveonlinetesting</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">XXXXXX</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">YYYYYYY</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
        <property name="c3p0.min_size">5</property>
        <property name="c3p0.max_size">20</property>
        <property name="c3p0.timeout">1800</property>
        <property name="c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
    </session-factory>
```

Kindly help as I am stuck in this issue.

Comment: Is MySQL running? Does the DB exist? Anything in the logs at DEBUG level?

Comment: Where's the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: Yes, hibernate is running. I have fixed that issue by fixing the database username, which was incorrect. Now I get an error for table doesnt exist as the table is right there. The error I get is: ERROR "ajp-bio-/127.0.0.1-9710"-exec-46 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Table 'brutteng_adaptiveonlinetesting.Authorities' doesn't exist